# Use two variables for require package in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to include two variables for a single package that is required in JavaScript?

I have an example here:

```
$ = require('jquery');
```

At the moment I simply use `$` however some of my project uses `jQuery` which I cannot change.

```
$, jQuery = require('jquery');
```

However this did not work which was expected to be honest.

This works however it isn't ideal as it will be requiring the package twice wont it?

```
$ = require('jquery');
jQuery = require('jquery');
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not just `$ = require('jquery'); jQuery = $;`

Comment: Can you explain the context of this? If `jQuery` is a global variable then why require it?

Comment: Why not using IIFE? `(function ($) { /* jquery code here */ }(jQuery))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var $ = jQuery = require('jquery');
```